# Placing text in div

Tags: css, html

At the top of my page I have a header (div) with just a few px distance to the top of the page. In the div I got my page title and Its placing itself in the top left corner (wich is normal). But it down at the bottom of the div (still at the right).
This is my html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>x</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #cdffaf;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h1 {
margin-top: 5px;    
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "But it down at the bottom of the div". What do you want (or see) at the bottom of the div?

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Where do you want the text to be? You're question isn't clear.

Comment: use developer tools to check the elements. maybe they're inheriting css.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JRfdB/)?

Comment: @Vucko Not a good way to do it :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien why not ? Using `position` is more cross browser supported then using `display:table-cell;`, isn't it ?

Comment: @Vucko Absolute will take it out of the document flow, also it won't reserve space in the actual document flow

Comment: @Mr.Alien but in OP question there is only one element that will get out of the document flow.

Comment: @Vucko May be he provided a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: bottom;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxc2e/)

[Color Changed (For Visibility)](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxc2e/1/)